# Create a bar chart on first row of correlation matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, bar-chart, correlation

I have a dataframe with 6 variables for which I have created a correlation matrix using corr_matrix = data.corr(). I want to create a bar chart with the values below of 0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.1 and 0.95 only to get correlations of with close_returns only (disregarding the correlation of close_returns with itself = 1.0). There seems to be an issue in terms of converting the values in the correlation matrix to float to use for the bar chart.

```
          close_returns open    high      low       close_price  volume     
close_returns   1.0     0.03    0.8       0.02      0.1           0.95
open            ...     ....    ...       ....      ...           ....
high            ...     ....    ...       ....      ...           ....
low             ...     ....    ...       ....      ...           ....
close_price     ...     ....    ...       ....      ...           ....
volume          ...     ....    ...       ....      ...           ....
```

Currently I am having to assign the correlations to a variable manually like below. I have tried converting the correlation matrix into float using corr_open2 = pd.to_numeric(corr_open) but doesn't work.

```
corr_matrix = data.corr()
corr_matrix

corr_open=0.03
corr_high=0.8
corr_low=0.02
corr_close_price=0.1
corr_volume=0.95


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('open', 'high', 'low', 'close_price', 'volume')
 y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
correlation = [0.03, 0.8, 0.02, 0.1, 0.95]
# this does not work 
# correlation = [corr_open, corr_high, corr_low, corr_close, corr_volume]

plt.bar(y_pos, correlation, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects, fontsize=9, rotation=90)
plt.ylabel('Correlation', fontsize=11)
plt.yticks(size = 9)
plt.title('Correlations with Close Returns', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try corr_matrix.values ?

Comment: Thank you, I think though that has converted into an array that is not allowing me to plot the values from. The output for correlation is now: [array([[0.03]]), array([[0.08]]), array([[0.02]]), array([[0.1]]), array([[0.95]). When I try to plot with the same code, it gives me the error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. I had used the same code except now for example, corrr_open is defined as corr_open=corr_matrix.values[:1,1:2] now

Comment: @JensHumrich I have tried correlation = corr_matrix.values[:1,1:6] which now gives me the values output as: array([[0.03, 0.08, 0.02, 0.1, 0.95]]). Unfortunately it still seems to be an array as I am still getting: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem well. Since corr_matrix is a data frame you can use iloc to access the elements

```
correlation = [corr_matrix['close_returns'].iloc[1], corr_matrix['close_returns'].iloc[2],corr_matrix['close_returns'].iloc[3],corr_matrix['close_returns'].iloc[4]]
```